# Use JSON schema in Pubsub topic subscription

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, schema, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

Can we create Pubsub topic subscription with a json schema and not with a avro schema file?
does the file need to be of extension ".avsc"? can we use ".json" instead?
Data is avro.

AVSC files contents looks like:

```
    {
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "twitter_schema",
  "namespace" : "com.miguno.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "username",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Name of the user account on Twitter.com"
  }, {
    "name" : "tweet",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "The content of the user's Twitter message"
  }, {
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Unix epoch time in seconds"
  } ],
  "doc:" : "A basic schema for storing Twitter messages"
}
```

Json files contents looks like:

```
{
"schema": {
    "fields": [{
        "name": "username",
        "type": "string",
        "doc": "Name of the user account on Twitter.com"
    }, {
        "name": "tweet",
        "type": "string",
        "doc": "The content of the user's Twitter message"
    }, {
        "name": "timestamp",
        "type": "long",
        "doc": "Unix epoch time in seconds"
    }]
}
```

}

Getting the below error when i tried to create subscription with json schema.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only  Avro and Protocol Buffer schemas are supported with Cloud Pub/Sub schemas. The extension of the file does not matter. Note that the Avro schema is valid JSON. The second schema is not a valid AVRO schema, which is why an error is being returned.

Comment: okay got it.. is there any documentation that mentions the same?

Comment: Yes, it is in the schema documentation: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/schemas#schema_types

Comment: `data` is bytes, so why cannot JSONSchema be used within UTF8 `BytesString` types?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The types of schemas for which support has been implemented is not dependent on the type of the data field.